# How to convert XSD to JSON schema directly in Java

Tags: java, json, xsd, jackson

can anybody suggest how to convert XSD schema to JSON schema using Java?

I have tried so many ways, almost all the ways generating class files using com.fasterxml.jackson libraries and then converting it to JSON which is not possible in my case.

here are the links I have tried

https://dzone.com/articles/generating-json-schema-xsd

http://marxsoftware.blogspot.in/2015/06/json-schema-xsd-jaxb-jackson.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide your own written code so we can discuss about.

Comment: actually i have requirement that i will get XSD schema as input, then i have to convert it into JSON schema and give it as output.

I have tried as it is code in [link]https://dzone.com/articles/generating-json-schema-xsd [link].but in this way it is generating pojo classes manually which is not possible in my case.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: Do you want to build on-demand conversion from some service? or you need to do it at build time? like maven plugin?

Comment: I want to build on-demand like a service. I will get the XML schema as input and I need to get the equivalent JSON schema as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to directly transform XSD into JSON Schema using Jsonix library

1. Download jsonix schema compiler from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hisrc.jsonix/jsonix-schema-compiler-full)

   The downloaded jar name would be something like below based on downloaded version
   `jsonix-schema-compiler-full-2.3.9.jar`
2. Open command prompt or linux shell and navigate to the above jar directory.
3. Execute below command from this directory
   `java -jar jsonix-schema-compiler-full-2.3.9.jar -generateJsonSchema -p FOOD schemas/food.xsd`
   Note: in above command `schemas/food.xsd` is the relative path of XSD schema file
4. Above step will generate two files in the current directory
   a. schema file (FOOD.jsonschema)
   b. mapping file (FOOD.js)
5. The schema file with .jsonschema extenstion is the desired equivalent JSON Schema.